# how to find out walking time between to nodes?

Tags: julia

Is there any option in routing package of graph.jl or osmx.jl or any other routing package to find out the walking time of any edges? Right now inside o f a map when I look at weights `map.w` is shows a distance while having car? Is that right? how to know the distance or the time it takes to walk from i to j.

Comment: Why don't you divide the distance by the speed of walking to get the walking time?

Comment: @mkrieger1 that's a good point actually. Thanks! but I wanted to find out if it's available automatically

Comment: This is supported by OpenStreetMapX.jl (see the answer below). However, since walking just depends on the distance the approach suggested by mkrieger1 seems to be a goof idea :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume using data from tutorial:

```
using OpenStreetMapX
map_file_path = joinpath(dirname(pathof(OpenStreetMapX)),"..","test/data/reno_east3.osm")
mx = get_map_data(map_file_path, use_cache=false, trim_to_connected_graph=true);
```

Normaly an OSM map is build around road classes. For each road class you have some driving speeds:

```
julia> OpenStreetMapX.SPEED_ROADS_URBAN
Dict{Int64, Float64} with 8 entries:
  5 => 50.0
  4 => 70.0
  6 => 40.0
  7 => 20.0
  2 => 90.0
  8 => 10.0
  3 => 90.0
  1 => 100.0
```

These are however driving speeds for  cars. Let us assume that people walk 5km/h and walking speed does not depend on the road class. Than you can do:

```
SPEEDS_ROADS_WALK = Dict(1:8 .=> 5.0)
```

Suppose you want to walk between 2 OSM nodes `1897440773` and `2445740506`:

```
julia> fastest_route(mx, 1897440773, 2445740506,speeds=SPEEDS_ROADS_WALK)
([1897440773, 3149568876, 3149568759, 140328042, 140328045, 140328047, 3149568878, 3149568997, 2445740506], 710.5468521109882, 511.59373351991167)
```

You can see the distance is 710 meters and the walk takes 511 seconds.

Now let if you want a walking time for each pair of nodes on the map you can do:

```
julia> walk_times = Dict( mx.e .=>  OpenStreetMapX.network_travel_times(mx, SPEEDS_ROADS_WALK))
Dict{Tuple{Int64, Int64}, Float64} with 3983 entries:
  (140377668, 140377665)           => 63.315
  (140236662, 1895015747190256479) => 16.3884
  (2440185561, 2440185544)         => 87.9369
  (140428209, 140254787)           => 153.809
  (3625693298, 3625693640)         => 65.4547
  (140233521, 140312783)           => 241.643
...
```

Now `walk_times` is dictionary that tells how long it takes to walk around the city. You can easily use it with the vector from `fastest_route` to get times for each pair of nodes during a walk.

This approach is perhaps more useful when you have different speeds for different road classes. Yet as you can see it can be used with walking too.